# How to format a date and write square brackets in dayjs?

Tags: javascript, dayjs

In dayjs, I want to get the following date time string:

```
25-01-2024 [17:29]
```

However, when writing square brackets in the format method it's showing

```
25-01-2024 HH:mm
```

How to escape square brackets in dayjs?

```
import dayjs from 'dayjs'

export const formatDateTime = (dateString: string) => {
  const parsedDate = dayjs(dateString)
  const formattedDate = parsedDate.format('DD-MM-YYYY [HH:mm]')
  return formattedDate
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
dayjs().format('DD-MM-YYYY [[]HH:mm]')
```

But I hope there is a better solution

Comment: why do you hope? it works!